# BxSlider, наивный вопрос

Tags: css, bxslider

Почему не отображаются изображения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="slider/css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
      *{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       list-style:none;
       text-decoration: none;
      }
   .mainSlider{
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
      }
      .bxslider img{
       position:relative;
       max-width:100%;
      }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>

<section class="mainSlider">
 <ul class="bxslider">
   <li><img src="slider/images/pic.jpg" alt="pic"/></li>
   <li><img src="slider/images/pic2.jpg" alt="pic1"/></li>
   <li><img src="slider/images/pic3.jpg" alt="pic3"/></li>
 </ul>
</section>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="slider/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

вставлял `js` и  в `head` и после `body` но после перезагрузки страницы появляется на мгновение и пропадает и всегда работает прелоадер, **минусами делу не поможете**
Путь до изображений вроде бы верный - чуть голову не сломал уже!
Изменилась ошибка : скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что консоль пишет? А что вместо фоток? квадратики сломанные или что?

Comment: err-file-not-found - но так писало даже тогда когда и работал этот плагин, я не знаю что думать , миллион раз его применял и всё было нормально

Comment: Как файл not found? конкретнее. ошибка, строка, что точно написано, если строка то где и пр..... работает ли слайдер с данной версией jquery?

Comment: Возможно ошибаюсь но поставьте слеш перед "slider" что бы "/slider/images/pic3.jpg"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ни какой файл - просто так пишет и всё , всегда так пишет

Comment: @BroouzerKing попробовал - тоже самое

Comment: сделайте скрин ошибки( разверните ее перед этим) и прикрепите к вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/EEn3/awz7Vw9a8  вот вся вёрстка - я в осадке - скрин сделаю - указывает на фалы jpg - но open link new tab открываются

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в версии jquery. Поставьте 2.0 (ну или 2.1.1) или 1.8 как в примере доков написано

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  сделайте ответом - заработало , но с google api не работало - а с сайта jquery заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуясь различными плагинами, основанными на `jquery` в случае если они отказываются функционировать, хотя на демках всё работает: следует попробовать несколько разных версий `jquery`. Возможно плагин работает не на той версии, на которой вы ожидаете.

Понятно, что многие гонятся за новинками и ставят новые версии, однако не все плагины успевают (или в принципе имеют возможность) переиначить под новые версии `jquery`.

В целом, этот самый `bxSlider` не работает с `jquery` версии 3.1.0 и даже 3.0.0. Но, судя по пунктам в [описании](http://bxslider.com/), работает с 1.8 и вроде с 2.0

Как следствие нужно поставить `jquery` именно одну из данных версий. Если конечно у вас весь проект не завязан на другой версии)) В этом случае придется решать еще и эту задачку. Но об этом в следующей серии... %)